# PHP get time from personal identity number under 1970

Tags: php, date, date-conversion

I have problem, I can't get time from personal identity number under 1970, I need to solve that, but using time. My function looks like. I don't know which way I can go. Thanks!

```
    function getBirthDayFromRd($rd){

$day = substr($rd,4,2);
$month = substr($rd, 2,2);
$year = substr($rd, 0,2);

if($month>=51 and $month<=62){ 
$month = $month - 50;
    }

$time = strtotime($day.".".$month.".".$year);

return date("d.m.Y", $time);


}
```

Comment: What is a valid value for `$rd`? And what output do you expect from this function?

Comment: Valid value is for example 920610 this will show 10.06.1992, but if it is 690610 it's have wrong counting, becouse time is from 1970

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime()` fails due to its being tied to the Unix epoch which does not support dates prior to 1970. Just use DateTime which can handle pre-1970 dates and convert dates easily:

```
function getBirthDayFromRd($rd){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymd',$rd);
    if($date->format('Y') > date("Y")) {
         $date->modify('-100 years');
    }
    return $date->format('d.m.Y');
}
```

[`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) parses your date and creates the `DateTime` object. Then we just call `DateTime::format()` to format it in the desired format.

**update**

Just fixed a bug where pre-1970 dates were shown 100 years in the future.

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/314955)

Comment: + however, it is worth mentioning that `strtotime()` can't be used because it is based on the [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: Thank you very much! I looking for somethink like this. I will try and give u rep.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it another way, but u started me up.

```
if($year < 70){
        $year = $year+1900;
        $time = date_create_from_format("d.m.Y", $day.".".$month.".".$year);
        return date_format($time, "d.m.Y");
    }else{

$time = strtotime($day.".".$month.".".$year);

return date("d.m.Y", $time);
}
```